# How to deserialize service bus message SystemProperties.LockToken into own class c#?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I have below code to de-serialize message properties into my own class but how to get default message properties into that same class?

```
 var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
 var testdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(data);
```

I want this message property also into MyClass 
`message.SystemProperties.LockToken`

```
 public class CheckException
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LockToken is a string property in [Message.SystemPropertiesCollection()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message.systempropertiescollection?view=azure-dotnet), you can assign  the SystemProperties.LockToken as

```
 CheckException checkException = new CheckException();
 checkException.LockToken = message.SystemProperties.LockToken;
```

Comment: 1. `LockToken` is a string property. Why would it throw an exception? 2. Why make `CheckException.LockToken` a static property?

Comment: 1. There is no `NullPointer` in .NET. Do you mean `NullReferenceException`? You are also not correct. setting a `null` value to a property doesn't throw an exception, unless something weird is going on in the setter. 2. The OP actually wanted `LockToken` in `MyClass`. I don't know how `CheckException` got into the question.

Answer (score 3):

The `LockToken` is just a string. Why not just set it to a property, like

```
testdata.LockToken = message.SystemProperties.LockToken;
```